# Iphone App crashing on launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

My simple iphone app is crashing on launch, it says *"the application downloadText quit unexcpectedly"* None of these windows that pop up when a mac app crashes and has a send to Apple button. My .h is below and I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could give me a hand as to what's wrong?

```
#import "downloadTextViewController.h"

@implementation downloadTextViewController


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];
    NSLog(myPath);
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

    if (fileExists)
    {
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        textView.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        [values release];
    }

    // notification
    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // add yourself to the dispatch table 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
                                               object:myApp];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)fetchData {
    /// Show activityIndicator / progressView

    NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://simpsonatyapps.com/exampletext.txt"]
                                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                 timeoutInterval:1.0];

    NSURLConnection *downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];

    if (downloadConnection)
        downloadedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    else {
        /// Error message
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)downloadConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [downloadedData appendData:data];

    NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    textView.text = file;

    /// Remove activityIndicator / progressView
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
}

- (NSString *) saveFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedddata.plist"];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textView.text,nil];
    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [values release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}


@end
```

Edit:
The console comes up with:

```
21/03/10 2:32:19 PM downloadText[3548] Stack: 
  ( 8307803, 2474450491, 8466881, 2787944, 2786485, 25429108, 8210735, 25423659, 
    25431927, 24117515, 24111079, 24110797, 8337, 23594443, 23632310, 23620404, 
    23602815, 23629921, 134489, 8092544, 8088648, 23596565, 23633839, 8252 )
```

Comment: You really need to post the dump reason so that I don't have to make a project in xcode to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console for exception reports.  [Spotlight search for "Console" application if you're lazy. ;-]  Any stack trace there to provide clues?

Run in the simulator in debug mode.  Set a breakpoint at the start of viewDidLoad, plus anywhere in your code from any stack trace left in the Console.

Does putting the call to "[super viewDidLoad]" first (instead of last) help?  If that's doing any work, it might be tripping up your viewDidLoad.  Check the Console output first though -- I tend to make code changes only when I understand what's going wrong, or I can use it to rule out potential causes.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the console comes up with:
21/03/10 2:32:19 PM downloadText[3548] Stack: (
    8307803,
    2474450491,
    8466881,
    2787944,
    2786485,
    25429108,
    8210735,
    25423659,
    25431927,
    24117515,
    24111079,
    24110797,
    8337,
    23594443,
    23632310,
    23620404,
    23602815,
    23629921,
    134489,
    8092544,
    8088648,
    23596565,
    23633839,
    8252
)